# Using Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR to extract uppercase data separated by underscores

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

sample column data:

```
Failure on table TOLL_USR_TRXN_HISTORY:
Failure on table DOCUMENT_IMAGES:
Error in CREATE_ACC_STATEMENT() [line 16]
```

I am looking for a way to extract only the uppercase words (table names) separated by underscores. I want the whole table name, the maximum is 3 underscores and the minimum is 1 underscore. I would like to ignore any capital letters that are initcap.

Comment: WIth your data, should CREATE_ACC_STATEMENT be extracted or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [`regexp_substr()`:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm)

```
select regexp_substr(str, '[A-Z_]{3,}', 1, 1, 'c')
from (select 'Failure on table TOLL_USR_TRXN_HISTORY' as str from dual) x;
```

The pattern says to find substrings with capital letters or underscores, at least 3 characters long.  The `1, 1` means start from the first position and return the first match.  The `'c'` makes the search case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You may use such [a SQL Select statement](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b4194/38) for each substituted individual line 
( `Failure on table TOLL_USR_TRXN_HISTORY` in the below case ) 
from your text :

```
select regexp_replace(q.word, '[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+', '') as word 
  from
(
  select substr(str,nvl(lag(spc) over (order by lvl),1)+1*sign(lvl-1),
         abs(decode(spc,0,length(str),spc)-nvl(lag(spc) over (order by lvl),1))) word, 
         nvl(lag(spc) over (order by lvl),1) lg
    from
  (
    with tab as
      ( select 'Failure on table TOLL_USR_TRXN_HISTORY' str from dual )
        select instr(str,' ',1,level) spc, str, level lvl
          from tab 
       connect by level <= 10
  )
) q
where lg > 0
    and upper(regexp_replace(q.word, '[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+', '')) 
      = regexp_replace(q.word, '[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+', '')
  and ( nvl(length(regexp_substr(q.word,'_',1,1)),0) 
      + nvl(length(regexp_substr(q.word,'_',1,2)),0) 
      + nvl(length(regexp_substr(q.word,'_',1,3)),0)) > 0
  and   nvl(length(regexp_substr(q.word,'_',1,4)),0)  = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way to get only table name from below error message , the below query will work only if table_name at end in the mentioned way

```
with t as( select 'Failure on table TOLL_USR_TRXN_HISTORY:' as data from dual)
SELECT RTRIM(substr(data,instr(data,' ',-1)+1),':') from t
```

New Query for all messages :

```
 select  replace (replace ( 'Failure on table TOLL_USR_TRXN_HISTORY:
Failure on table DOCUMENT_IMAGES:' , 'Failure on table', ' ' ),':',' ') from dual
```

Comment: what if string is 'Failure on table TOLL_USR_TRXN_HISTORY TOLL_USR_TRXN_HISTORY2:' ..? Then, returns `TOLL_USR_TRXN_HISTORY2` only. And there's no filter for all uppercase letters and underscores. And returns only the last word of the sentence.

Comment: Yes  Barbaro ... it wont work . This will only pick last word

Comment: I have updated query to handle mutilple messages ...since error messages are common I went with this query .... but I see your query was awesome whatever it can be :-)